# How is it possible that putting code in a separate function could increase performance?

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I have a mildly large function (about 80 lines of code without comments) that I'm optimizing.

As part of trying to let the profiler do the work for me, I took 2 chunks of code and put them in separate functions (this is supposed to be only temporary until I can put them back in).

The interesting part is this:
My test case took 29.8 seconds
After I put the first chunk into a separate function I saw the small performance loss due to function call overhead. (30.2 seconds)
When I put the second chunk of code into a separate function I got a pretty huge performance gain down to 24.2 seconds

The second chunk of code is an insertion into a rather large linked list which I plan to replace with a binary tree or something, but still this 20% improvement is pretty confusing to me.

**tl;dr: Trying to optimize code and noticed that putting block of code into separate function gave me a 20% performance increase.  How is that possible?**

Edit: confirmed running in release build as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By extracting this block of code you made the function simpler. Maybe that helped the compiler to efficiently compile the function. It might have relieved register pressure because there are less local variables.

Sometimes, it is just coincidence. **Jiggling code around randomly is very likely to change performance (in both ways).** Maybe you just happened to hit an improvement instead of a deterioration.

**Why does "jiggling" change performance?** It might change address alignment, branch prediction, the compilers view on what is hot and what is cold, CPU instruction cache usage.

All of these things are implementation details from a semantic standpoint. Yet they influence performance. They are quite unpredictable because they work on a very low level and are very complex.

Comment: I like that answer and thats what I'm currently going with.

I need to find a resource on the type of compiler optimization actionscript does otherwise I feel like I'm just stumbling in the dark.

Comment: I added a little more thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Without code examples, it is hard to give a decent explanation but the answer of usr is very true in the case of most programming languages.

However, I do have my reservations when it comes to the Flash compiler.  From experience, self-inlining (so the opposite of what you have done) is generally one of the best ways to optimize functions in flash as the function call overhead is very high.

That being said, I would agree with usr that having less local variables is most likely the reason why you would see a performance gain.  Flash does not have block-level scope meaning that all variables declared in your function are allocated memory when the function is called.  If your second block of code declares variables that are only useful in that specific block of code and that this code is only run sometimes (if it is in an if statement), that could explain the performance boost.

Example of case where you could see a performance gain :

```
public function foo() : void
{
    var bar : MyObj;
    //do stuff with bar

    if(someValuesAreTrue)
    {
        var jad  : oObj;
        var jad2 : oObj;
        //etc
        //do something with jad
    }
}

//changed to 
public function foo() : void
{
    var bar : MyObj;
    //do stuff with bar

    if(someValuesAreTrue)
    {
        subFunc();
    }
}
private function subFunc() : void
{
    var jad  : oObj;
    var jad2 : oObj;
    //etc
    //do something with jad
}
```

If this is not the type of situation you are in, I would be very curious to see some code as it could give better insight to other performance boosting alternatives to self-inlining.